# Stream not reading entire image

Tags: java, android, image, sockets

I am sending an image from java pc application to android application through sockets. My image that I send does not full read into the android byte[] for some reason and it has varying results for how much of the image is decoded. Here is my code

Desktop:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 59900);
           // BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            Robot r = new Robot();
            Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);

            byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(baos.size()).array();
            outputStream.write(size);
            outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
            //outputStream.flush();

            System.out.println("Flushed: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            //Thread.sleep(12000);
            System.out.println("Closing: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            socket.close();
```

Android code

```
 ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(59900);
        Socket socket = server.accept();

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("Reading: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
        inputStream.read(sizeAr);
        int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
        byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
        inputStream.read(imageAr);
       // ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr);

        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAr, 0, size);
```

Here is a picture of what the result looks like [image]

Comment: ByteBuffer.allocate(4) .. try changing here 4 to 16 and see what happens

Comment: No image is produced when I do this.

Comment: Bear in mind that _inputStream.read(imageAr)_ does not necessarily read full array length. You need to verify the return value to see actual byte count read.

Answer (score 0):

As you're closing the socket after sending the image, you don't need to send the count, and therefore you don’t need the `ByteBuffer`, the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, or the `ByteArrayInputStream`. Or the sleep. Get rid of them all and write the image directly to the socket output stream, and read it directly from the socket input stream with `ImageIO.read()`.

Comment: Relying on socket close is a bad idea. You need to know when the image is complete, so you need to send the count. TCP has no time requirement, you can receive the last byte 3 minutes later.

Comment: @ElderBug The close is is the OP's idea, not mine, but your comment doesn't make sense. The image is complete when `ImageIO.read()` returns. TCP's so-called lack of 'time requirements' has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then you should mention `ImageIO` in your answer. _"read it directly from the socket input stream"_ means `InputStream.read()` to me.

Comment: @ElderBug No it doesn't. That's just a willful misinterpretation.

Comment: Yes it does since you only said intput stream and never mentionned `ImageIO`

Comment: @ElderBug `ImageIO.read()` reads from the input stream it is given. Your misinterpretation doesn't hold water.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception that reading N bytes from a socket will return N bytes. A socket read call will return **whenever it wants** (usually when there is a time gap in the bytes received, which highly depends on the network). N is just the maximum number of bytes.

To solve this issue, you can either loop until you have the number of bytes required, or use specialized streams like `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`, which offer the `write()` and `readFully()` method. They also provide the `writeInt()` and `readInt()`, that make sending the size easier.

Comment: A read call does not 'return whenever it wants': it blocks until at least one byte is available, or end of stream or an error occurs. `DataOutputStream` does not 'offer the `readFully()` method'.

Comment: @EJP Oh really ? Are you a kid ? Of course ouput stream doesn't have a read method. Why would you downvote for that ? Ouput streams always write fully, they don't need such method.

Comment: I am commenting on what you posted. You wrote 'offer', which is plural, and therefore encompasses both the subjects of your sentence, which are, and I quote, `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`. It reains open to you to correct your post.

Comment: @EJP Please, stop that. Am I downvoting your answer because you said _"write and read with `ImageIO.read()`"_ and you forgot `ImageIO.write()` ? What you are doing is just plain stupid.